# Go: decoding json with one set of json tags, and encoding to a different set of json tags

Tags: json, go

I have an application that consumes data from a third-party api. I need to decode the json into a struct, which requires the struct to have json tags of the "incoming" json fields. The outgoing json fields have a different naming convention, so I need different json tags for the encoding.

I will have to do this with many different structs, and each struct might have many fields.

**What is the best way to accomplish this without repeating a lot of code?**

Example Structs:

```
// incoming "schema" field names
type AccountIn struct {
    OpenDate string `json:"accountStartDate"`
    CloseDate string `json:"cancelDate"`
}


// outgoing "schema" field names
type AccountOut struct {
    OpenDate string `json:"openDate"`
    CloseDate string `json:"closeDate"`
}
```

Comment: How many things do you have to repeat?  If you don't have too many types making multiple structs is probably easier.

Comment: It's way too much. I've considered it, but can't fathom the tediousness of that (and maintenance nightmare). Hence, I need help from people smarter than I am.

Comment: Computers are good at tedious things -- I would probably generate the code for the translated types. I unfortunately can't think of a clean, generic solution off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the coming change on Go 1.8 would help you, it will allow to 'cast' types even if its JSON tags definition is different: This https://play.golang.org/p/Xbsoa8SsEk works as expected on 1.8beta, I guess this would simplify your current solution

Comment: The language specification change is described here https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.8#language

Comment: Just to be clear, Go doesn't have 'casting' but does allow type conversion, which is what this approach uses.

Answer (score 3):

A bit an uncommon but probably quite well working method would be to use a intermediate format so u can use different readers and writers and therefore different tags. For example https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure which allows to convert a nested map structure into struct 
types. Pretty similar like json unmarshal, just from a map.

```
// incoming "schema" field names
type AccountIn struct {
    OpenDate string `mapstructure:"accountStartDate" json:"openDate"`
    CloseDate string `mapstructure:"cancelDate" json:"closeDate"`
}

// from json to map with no name changes
temporaryMap := map[string]interface{}{}
err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &temporaryMap)

// from map to structs using mapstructure tags
accountIn := &AccountIn{}
mapstructure.Decode(temporaryMap, accountIn)
```

Later when writing (or reading) u will use directly the json functions which will then use the json tags.

Answer (score 1):

If it's acceptable to take another round trip through `json.Unmarshal` and `json.Marshal`, and you don't have any ambiguous field names within your various types, you could translate all the json keys in one pass by unmarshaling into the generic structures used by the `json` package:

```
// map incoming to outgoing json identifiers
var translation = map[string]string{
    "accountStartDate": "openDate",
    "cancelDate":       "closeDate",
}

func translateJS(js []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(js, &m); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    translateKeys(m)
    return json.MarshalIndent(m, "", "  ")
}

func translateKeys(m map[string]interface{}) {
    for _, v := range m {
        if v, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            translateKeys(v)
        }
    }

    keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }

    for _, k := range keys {
        if newKey, ok := translation[k]; ok {
            m[newKey] = m[k]
            delete(m, k)
        }
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nXmWlj7qH9

Answer (score 0):

This might be a Naive Approach but is fairly easy to implement:-

```
func ConvertAccountInToAccountOut(AccountIn incoming) (AccountOut outcoming){
    var outcoming AccountOut
    outcoming.OpenDate = incoming.OpenDate
    outcoming.CloseDate = incoming.CloseDate

    return outcoming
}

var IncomingJSONData AccountIn
resp := getJSONDataFromSource()  // Some method that gives you the Input JSON
err1 := json.UnMarshall(resp,&IncomingJSONData)
OutGoingJSONData := ConvertAccountInToAccountOut(IncomingJSONData)

if err1 != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error in UnMarshalling JSON ",err1)
}

fmt.Println("Outgoing JSON Data: ",OutGoingJSONData)
```